# Django python3 manage.py runserver won't run via VSC terminal (Mac)

Tags: python, django, macos, visual-studio, anaconda

Trying to run this command:

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

via VSC terminal and get this error:

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 13, in main
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

But! when I run it via the Mac terminal, it works well.

I have verified and:

- Virtual env is running (via Anaconda)
- Django is installed (as it is running on the Mac terminal)

is it something with VCS setting I need to tweak?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what does `python3 -m pip list` show?

Comment: `python3 -m pip list`  has not Django, while `pip list` do show it

Comment: then the python you're running the server with is different to the one you installed django into

Comment: when running this 'python3 -m pip list' in the Mac terminal (outside VCS) I do get Django in the list.

Comment: That would be because it’s using a different python to the one you’re running the server with

Answer (score 0):

After restarting VSC, I go an message that VSC noticed I got issues with the terminal and offered to change the path of the env file. After that I restated the terminal and now I get the same output, both with `python3 -m pip list` and `pip list`.